# Gradle never creates build folder

Tags: android, gradle

When I try to run my android app I always get a

> The APK file D:\Projects\Games\AppName\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk does not exist on disk.
>   Error while Installing APK

error.

There isn't even a build folder! What shall I do?

Comment: check if it has been compiled at all, because to me it seems it hasn't

Comment: Well, I think it has finished. I have no compile errors and the log says "Gradle build finished in 1s 278ms". No Gradle errors, however, when I launch the app I get the unexpected message.

Comment: Does Gradle produce an apk file? Could you show manifest of your app?

Comment: No it doesn't. It should be in the build folder, but there's no folder called "build". Anyway everything was working right before I updated my Gradle plugin.

Comment: You should have started with `I updated Gradle plugin and can't build application anymore`. From which version to which version you updated?

Comment: I updated from 1.5 to 2.0 beta4, but it had even more issues so I downgraded and now the 1.5 has problems, too.

Comment: I'am not a Gradle pro, so i suggest that you create project from scratch and import all your code and resources. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution!

One of my java files used a library provided by Gradle, but somehow it forgot to add the dependency and give me any errors about it and there were no compile errors or similar things. After I deleted my project's .gradle folder, Gradle indexed all of my stuff in the project and showed the unknown file. I synced my project again and I got the library I needed. Now Android Studio launches my program.